# Testing embedded HTML form via Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, selenium-ide

I have an html page that has a small piece of JavaScript that further embeds an HTML form in a div tag (this div is identified by an ID).

I want to use Selenium IDE to test the form. I recorded a basic test to test the embedded form but Selenium seems to be failing. It cannot find the elements or the text.

I got the source of the parent html page but it does not have any Form html. Firefox allows you to see the Form html by going to 'This Frame->View Source'. The embedded html is whole html page not just the form - I mean it starts and ends with `<html>` tag

I was wondering how could I test the embedded form using Selenium IDE ? I searched a lot and found 'SelectFrame' but all the examples on the web include Java code (that I do not wish to get into) as opposed to plain HTML (I would like my test to be plain HTML Selenium test cases and would like to keep it simple).

Also, I doubt if 'SelectFrame' is going to help as the form gets embedded in a 'Div' tag and not in the frame.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you have a frame and frame have some name, please use this and let me know

```
   selectFrame   | frame name |
   verifytext    | text 
   selectWindow  | null            - this for release the frame
```

please show me once your script so that I will help you futher

Answer (score 0):

use

```
driver.switchTo().frame("marco");
```

replace "marco" with your own frame name

Comment: He's using the IDE and not WebDriver directly.

Comment: Mark is right cegprakash. I want something to work with IDE. Also, remember that its a Div not a frame.